# Port forwarding on Telstra Arcadyan (All device's IP are same)

Tags: wireless-networking, port-forwarding, minecraft

I have a Telstra Gateway Max and I use Telstra Arcadyan to port forward (for a Minecraft server). I followed usual steps you would normally follow when port forwarding. But when I tried to connect using my external IP, it didn't connect.

If I connect using my IPv4 address or localhost it works but it doesn't work with my external public IP. I went to canyouseeme.org on 2 computers and they both reported port 25565 to be open.

I checked my Minecraft server server.properties file and the port was set to 25565.

I also added a firewall rule on my machine that is hosting the server.

But I also saw that all IP addresses on the computers connected to the network were the same.

Thanks

Comment: All IP addresses could not have been the same - the Internet does not work that way. What is likely the case is they are all different, but behind NAT and you are seeing the report of the routers IP, which is fairly standard on home equipment.

Comment: Why does it shows the same IP address on whatsmyip.com?

Comment: Reread my answer. Also google NAT (or Network Address Translation).  The router is changing the IP address associated with requests leaving your network and then rewriting them on the way back. In this way you have 1 routable address but can have many devices - which conserves space and arguably makes your network less insecure.

Comment: Is it possible to port forward with NAT? Because people probably need to connect using my individual IP address to the server but I don't know that.

Comment: Its technically possible, but largely pointless because the connections coming in to the world won't reach your router.  (If your ISP were doubly incompetent and set up port forwarding on their router to your NAT router, then this would work - but it would also open you up to unwanted exposure because of all the other people associated with the relevant real IP.

Comment: Okay. Thank you!